# NoSuchElementException while solving a question. It is running on my vs code but when I try to submit it, it gives this exception

Tags: java

I don't know what is wrong with this code. I tried to run in my vs code and it is running as I want but when I'm trying to submit it in codeforces it is giving runtime error saying NosuchElementException.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SashaAndArrayColoring {
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t!=0){
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int arr[]=new int[n];
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            if(n==1){
                System.out.println("0");
            }else {
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++){
                sum=sum+(arr[n-(i+1)]-arr[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
            }
            
        }
    }   
}
```

6
5
1 5 6 3 4
1
5
4
1 6 3 9
6
1 13 9 3 7 2
4
2 2 2 2
5
4 5 2 2 3
These are the test cases they are working in my vs code but giving exception in codeforces in test case 1

Comment: All code kata sites have some specific code process that you must follow to read data from their systems.  It should be documented on the codeforces website.  Make sure you're following their pattern precisely.

Comment: `while(t!=0){` - `t` is not being changed inside the loop - it is looping for ever! The sites input is probably being closed after last input, causing the exception. Are you closing the input in VS Code? Probably code is not terminating on VS Code and is just waiting for more input (probably missing something in the empty line at the end of the loop)

Comment: yes I forgot to add the decrement statement for t. thank you @user16320675